# Endless loop while splitting a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement MergeSort as a homework assignment. I have been given a function called MergeSort which takes an input vector. Then, I have been given a Split and Merge function.

I know how MergeSort works, and I have implemented in Java multiple times, but I have always used arrays, and I haven't had much experience with pointers and references.

Here is what I have so far,

```
void Split(const std::vector<int>& input, std::vector<int>* output1, std::vector<int>* output2) {



    std::cout << "In split function" << std::endl;
    // this just prints the values in my vector
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << input[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (input.size() > 1) {


        int i = 0;
        int j = input.size();

        while (i <= j) {
            output1->push_back(input[i]);
            i++;


            if (i != j) {
                output2->push_back(input[j]);
                j--;
            }
        }



        std::vector<int> left= {};
        std::vector<int> right = {};

        Split(*output1, &left, &right);
        Split(*output2, &left, &right);
    }
}

void MergeSort(std::vector<int>* input){
    std::vector<int> output1= {};
    std::vector<int> output2 = {};
    std::cout << "Starting mergesort" << std::endl;
    Split(*input, &output1, &output2);

}
```

I also have a merge function which I don't want to include because its not relevant to my problem.

Right now, my code compiles but it gets stuck in an endless loop and gives me a segfault.

I have a main function that calls the MergeSort function with the values: {3, 5, 1, 2, 9, 4}

The Split function is called and then this is just printed to stdout until termination:

`In split function
3, 5, 1,`

Why am I getting stuck in this loop?

Comment: `input[j]` with `j = input.size()` exceeds bounds by one...

Comment: You beat me to it by about 1 minute Stephan.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have pointed out, this the index's of your arrays are wrong.

```
int i = 0;
int j = input.size();
```

Because of this, your loop ends up producing a `output1` to be `{3, 5, 1}`, which is then fed into `Split(...)`, producing `{3, 5, 1}`, again until the recursion leads to a seg fault.

```
int i = 0;
int j = input.size() - 1;
```

This will cause the `output1` array to actually shrink `{3, 5}`, leading to termination in the base case of `if(input.size() > 1)`

Comment: I fixed `j` , but now it endlessly loops for {3, 5} and then gives me a segfault.